# Does mongodb's find() return objects missing a field from the specified projection?

Tags: mongodb

If I have a mongodb containing this:

`{ _id:ObjectId(0), name:"foo", hits:5 }`

Will it get returned by this query:

`find({name:"foo"}, {hits:1, flow:1})`

If so, what will the returned object look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will, and it will look like this:

```
{ "_id": ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"), "hits": 5 }
```

`name` is omitted because it's not included in the projection, but `_id` is included by default.

Comment: Just a tip in addition to @JohnnyHK answer. In case you want to suppress _id to be appearing in results, you can do it by having _id set to 0 in projection. Ok, I have deleted my answer :)

Comment: ok, now I get it. In fact if the projection was {thing:1,_id:0} it would return an empty object : {}. For each object matching the query, SOMETHING will be returned, but it may not have any attributes set. The [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#result-projections), seemed to me to suggest that only objects containing the attributes specified in the projection would be returned.